# Regex: drop numbers with some symbols

Tags: python, regex

I try to clean my text. So I need to remove some numbers and also some combinations of numbers and symbols.

I have a string

```
s = '4/13/2022 2:20:03 pm from our side a more detailed analysis4 +7 (495) 797-8700 77-8282'
```

And I want to get

```
'pm from our side a more detailed analysis4'
```

I tried to use

```
re.compile(r'\b(?:/|-|\+|\:)(\d+)\b').sub(r' ', s)
```

but it returns me

```
'4   2   pm from our side a more detailed analysis4 +7 (495) 797  77 '
```

What I do wrong and how can I drop just numbers and combinations of number and a specific symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might match at least a single non word character surrounded by optional digits and trim the result

```
(?<!\S)\d*(?:[^\w\s]+\d*)+\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the leeft
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(?:[^\w\s]+\d*)+` Match 1+ times at least a non word character and optional digits
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bWXFZ0/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)\d*(?:[^\w\s]+\d*)+\s*"
s = "4/13/2022 2:20:03 pm from our side a more detailed analysis4 +7 (495) 797-8700 77-8282 kl-1381033 substr1.substr2.ab-2021-44228.a"

print(re.sub(pattern, "", s))
```

Output

```
ppm from our side a more detailed analysis4 kl-1381033 substr1.substr2.ab-2021-44228.a
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I avoid it if i have any letters like `kl-1381033`. This way I don't want to remove numbers

Comment: @ldevyataykina Like this? `(?<!\S)\d*(?:[^\w\s]+\d*)+\s*` https://regex101.com/r/bWXFZ0/1

Comment: It still doesn't work for constructions like that `substr1.substr2.ab-2021-44228.a`, it returns `substr substr ab a`

Comment: @ldevyataykina It does not match that string, see https://regex101.com/r/goUU1w/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression :

```
(?:\/|-|\+|\:|^|\(|\)| ) ?(\d+)
```

You can test it there : https://regex101.com/r/aANxBR/1

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to remove words that start with digits and symbols.

You could do:

```
import re 

s = '4/13/2022 2:20:03 pm from our side a more detailed analysis4 +7 (495) 797-8700 77-8282 kl-1381033 substr1.substr2.ab-2021-44228.a'

>>> ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if not re.match(r'[\d(+]\S+', w))
'pm from our side a more detailed analysis4 kl-1381033 substr1.substr2.ab-2021-44228.a'
```

Including a completely Python solution:

```
bad_start='0123456789+('
>>> ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w[0] not in bad_start)
'pm from our side a more detailed analysis4 kl-1381033 substr1.substr2.ab-2021-44228.a'
```